# Multiple overlayed plots in pyqtgraph (trouble binding an axis)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I am having a bit of a problem with my graph.  I can get both curves to plot at the same time, but the second plot seems to be bound to the left axis as well, does anyone know if I can have the right axis scale with the 2nd curve?
Here is a working short example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import random

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.login_widget = LoginWidget(self)
        self.login_widget.button.clicked.connect(self.plotter)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.login_widget)

    def plotter(self):
        self.data =[0]
        self.data2 = [0]
        self.curve = self.login_widget.plot.getPlotItem().plot()
        self.curve2 =self.login_widget.plot.getPlotItem().plot()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updater)
        self.timer.start(0)

    def updater(self):

        self.data.append(self.data[-1]+0.2*(0.5-random.random()) )
        self.curve.setData(self.data, pen=pg.mkPen('b', width=1))
        self.data2.append(self.data2[-1]+0.2*(0.5-random.random()) )
        self.curve2.setData(self.data2, pen=pg.mkPen('r', width=1))

class LoginWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
        pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start Plotting')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.plot = pg.PlotWidget(title='Force and Extension vs. Time')
        #self.plot.showGrid(x=True,y=True)
        self.plot.showAxis('right')
        p2 = pg.ViewBox()
        self.plot.scene().addItem(p2)
        p2.setXLink(self.plot)
        ax2 = self.plot.getAxis('right').linkToView(p2)
        ax = self.plot.getAxis('bottom')
        ax3 = self.plot.getAxis('right')
        ax3.setLabel('Extension', units='in.')
        ax.setLabel('Time', units='s')
        ay = self.plot.getAxis('left')
        ay.setLabel('Force', units='lbf')
        layout.addWidget(self.plot)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def pg_clear(self):
        self.plot.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Do you want to display the last n elements of both graphs?

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but my question was whether you want to show all the data from the beginning or only the last n data.

Comment: my apologies, all of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example shown in this [link](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/downloads/0.10.0/pyqtgraph-0.10.0-deb/pyqtgraph-0.10.0/examples/MultiplePlotAxes.py) I have implemented the following solution, I have added the necessary colors to the labels of each axis to easily recognize the data, I have also implemented the updateViews() function so that when I change the size of the Screen is displayed properly.

*Note:* I have modified the function that generates the data so that the changes are observed.

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.login_widget = LoginWidget(self)
        self.login_widget.button.clicked.connect(self.plotter)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.login_widget)

        self.curve = self.login_widget.it1
        self.curve2 =self.login_widget.it2

    def plotter(self):
        self.data =[0]
        self.data2 = [0]
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updater)
        self.timer.start(0)

    def updater(self):
        self.data.append(self.data[-1]+10*(0.5-random.random())) 
        self.curve.setData(self.data, pen=pg.mkPen('b', width=1))
        self.data2.append(self.data2[-1]+0.1*(0.5-random.random()))
        self.curve2.setData(self.data2, pen=pg.mkPen('r', width=1))

class LoginWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
        pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start Plotting')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.plot = pg.PlotWidget(title='Force and Extension vs. Time')
        layout.addWidget(self.plot)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        p1 = self.plot.plotItem
        p2 = pg.ViewBox()
        p1.showAxis('right')
        p1.scene().addItem(p2)
        p1.getAxis('right').linkToView(p2)
        p2.setXLink(p1)

        self.plot.getAxis('bottom').setLabel('Time', units='s')
        self.plot.getAxis('left').setLabel('Force', units='lbf', color="#0000ff")
        p1.getAxis('right').setLabel('Extension', units='in.', color="#ff0000")

        def updateViews():
            p2.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
            p2.linkedViewChanged(p1.vb, p2.XAxis)

        updateViews()
        p1.vb.sigResized.connect(updateViews)

        self.it1 = p1.plot()
        self.it2 = pg.PlotCurveItem()
        p2.addItem(self.it2)
```

Comment: is there any way I could get your contact info to maybe work with my company if we have any issues?